# Using a Facebook token received from a native iOS/ Android client

Tags: ios, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

We implement a native iOS application on top of our application server. We want to give the user the option to login with facebook account **BUT** we want the account creation to take place in **application server**.

As i understand, i need to login to facebook via iOS and pass the token to spring-social-facebook.

I want to ask if this is possible (create token in iOS and pass it to application server) and how can i achieve it?